# Why is $\frac{1}{4/3} - \frac{1}{3/2}$ not the same as $\bigl(\frac{4}{3} - \frac{3}{2}\bigr)^{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you have the problem:$$\frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}} - \frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}} =?$$

Why can't you change the problem to $(\frac{4}{3} - \frac{3}{2})^{-1}$   and get the same answer?

In the first scenario, the answer is $1/12$

In the second scenario, the answer is $-6$

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: One might ask, why would you expect those two numbers to be the same?

Comment: Isn't 1/(4/3) the same as (4/3)^-1 ?

Comment: @Jared Yes, that's right!  But $(a + b)^{-1}$ is not equal to $a^{-1} + b^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, $1/(4/3)$ is the same as $(4/3)^{-1}$.  But still, the original question stands.

Comment: It's a common error to think that the "blip of the blop" should be equal to the "blop of the blip".  (In this case, the issue is that the sum of the reciprocals is not equal to the reciprocal of the sum.)

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Why would it?

Comment: @Jared, you should mark an answer accepted if you feel your question has been answer.

Answer (score 10):

The original problem is $$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{y-x}{xy}$$
for specific values of $x,y$.  The modified problem is $$\frac{1}{x-y}$$

In order for them to be equal, $$\frac{y-x}{xy}=\frac{1}{x-y}$$
cross-multiplying, we get $$-(x-y)^2=xy$$
Expanding, we get $$-x^2+2xy-y^2=xy$$
or $$x^2-xy+y^2=0$$

The only real solutions this has are $x=0, y=0$, which are excluded since we are dividing by $x,y$.  Hence this proposed simplification is *never correct*, even accidentally.

Comment: +1 for "Hence this proposed simplification is *never correct*, even accidentally."

Comment: I think that does make a lot of sense, but I am still confused as to why then 1/(4/3) - 1/(3/2) and (4/3)^-1 - (3/2)^-1 are not the same thing, or rather don't give the same answer when solved, unless I am solving the second one wrong. Can't you eliminate dealing with fractions in the denominator by rewriting the problem as (4/3)^-1 - (3/2)^-1 ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}=x^{-1}$, yes.  The issue is that $x^{-1}-y^{-1}\neq (x-y)^{-1}$.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. Maybe my problem was in how I was trying to solve it. Is there a way to explain solving (4/3)^-1 - (3/2)^-1. Maybe I am missing some order of operations. I get (-1/6)^-1, or -6... I am sure I must be doing something wrong then.... If I make the denominators the same in each, and since they are both raised to the -1, can't I just simply subtract the one from the other then deal with the -1 exponent at the end...again, thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking why $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} \neq \frac{1}{a+b}$. Take $ a = b = 2$, for example. You would expect that adding a half plus a half would get you back to one, i.e. $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} = 1$, and certainly not a quarter, $\frac{1}{2+2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Let's say you have some function $f(x)$ that takes some number $x$ and spits out a different number $y$. Let's take $f(x) = 3\cdot x$. If we put in a number that is a sum of two other numbers, for example, $x = a+b$, then we have that $f(x) = f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$. Same if $x$ is some multiple of a different number, $x = 4\cdot a$, namely $f(x) = f(4\cdot a) = 4f(a)$. These properties only hold because we choose our $f(x)$ to be very specific, i.e. multiplication by $3$. In general they do not have to hold however! For example if $f(x) = x^2$, or $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

You are probably too used to functions behaving in the way $f(x) = 3\cdot x$ did, but if you look carefully almost everything that you can come up with will not have these nice properties.

Comment: Definitely! $x^{-1}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ mean the exact same thing. Purely for  educational purposes, could you maybe try to come up with three functions  (that aren't $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ or $f(x) = x^2$!) that do not have these nice properties that I just listed?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by ones that don't have those properties...

Comment: If we have $f(x) = x^2$ and we have a number $x = a+b$, then we have that, in general, $f(x) = f(a+b) \neq f(a) + f(b)$. For example, set $x = 5$ and $a = 2$, $b = 3$. We have that $f(5) = 5^2 = 25$, while $f(2)+f(3) = 2^2 + 3^2 = 4 + 9 = 13 \neq 25$. We say then that $f(x) = x^2$ is a non-linear function. The same holds for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, try it out with $x = 5$,$a = 2$ and b = 3$ for example. Can you come up with other functions that are non-linear?

Answer (score 2):

When calculating this answer you have to honor the order of operations. The error here is that $$(a+b)^c\ne a^c+b^c.$$  you have to perform addition and then apply the exponent. These two operations are not commutative. In other words, it is not the same to apply the exponent to each value before adding.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think that does make a lot of sense, but I am still confussed as to why then 1/(4/3) - 1/(3/2) and (4/3)^-1 - (3/2)^-1  are not the same thing. Can't you eliminate dealing with fractions in the denominator by rewriting the problem as (4/3)^-1 - (3/2)^-1 ?

Comment: Or am I just forgetting to solve first using an order of operations..?

Comment: What you have written is the same thing, but in your question you have it as $(\frac43-\frac32)^{-1}$ which is wrong. The correct way to carry out the original computation is to apply reciprocal and then subtract.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$(A-B)^{-1}\not=A^{-1}-B^{-1}.$$
Note that we have$$(\color{red}{A-B})^{-1}=\frac{1}{\color{red}{A-B}}.$$
For your case, we have

$$\left(\dfrac{4}{3}-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{4}{3}-\dfrac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now...Has been a while for me...haha

Answer (score 1):

It looks like based on your post that you want to know why $\frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}} - \frac{1}{\frac{3}{2}}$ is *not* equal to $\frac{1}{\frac{4}{3} - \frac{3}{2}}$.

In general, you can only say a property holds like, in your case, $(a + b)^{-1} = a^{-1} + b^{-1}$ if you can show it holds for every $a$ and $b$.  But as you pointed out in your question, if $a = \frac{4}{3}$ and $b = \frac{3}{2}$, this property doesn't hold.  Therefore, it's **not true** that $(a + b)^{-1} = a^{-1} + b^{-1}$ holds.  The property is false, as your example perfectly showed.

Answer (score 0):

1/(4/3 - 3/2) is not the same as 1/4/3 -1/3/2 simply because the latter expression is equivalent to 3/4 - 2/3 which is 9-8 / 12 which 12^-1. 12 is not 4/3 - 3/2.   In general,  fractions can only be grouped together by adding NUMERATORS if the DOMINATORS are the same. Unless they are being divided by each other or multiplied.  The reason for this can be shown from first principles but I think it's common sense tbh.